# Select a directed SubGraph without sinks and sources

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following problem: Assume you have a large list of directed edges, that constitute a large graph. I would like to provide an initial subset of vertices and I need to know which additional vertices I need to select in order to

1. make sure that the resulting (sub)-graph is connected
2. make sure that I don't have sink/source vertices, i.e. all vertices have at least one incoming and one outgoing edge.
3. minimize the number of additional vertices

I don't have a working code (at least not for V8+). But assume the following directed edges:

```
ex = {"9" -> "7", "4" -> "6", "1" -> "9", "3" -> "5", "10" -> "8", 
   "5" -> "2", "2" -> "5", "9" -> "3", "3" -> "1", "7" -> "9", 
   "8" -> "6", "3" -> "10", "2" -> "1", "7" -> "4", "1" -> "4", 
   "2" -> "7", "5" -> "6", "7" -> "2"};

gr=Graph[ex, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Say, we initially choose vertices "1" and "3" and "7", then the subgraph has source/sinks:

```
Subgraph[gr, {"3", "1", "7"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Now, a possible completion of the graph without sinks/sources would be:

```
sgr=Subgraph[gr, {"3", "1", "9", "7"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[gr, sgr]
```

[image]

I understand that this problem might not have a unique solution. Any solution is fine for me. (The upgraded Graph capabilities of V8 are still mostly unexplored area for me, so I apologize for not having a working initial solution. My V7 approach stopped working so I hesitate in postin it here.)

I need to do this for a large set of directed edges (10000+) so performance might be an issue as well.

**Edit(new):**

Following up on Szabolcs comments & answer the following works very well.

```
badguys[gr_] := Union[sinks[gr], sources[gr]]
healthyGraph[gr_] := FixedPoint[VertexDelete[#, badguys[#]] &, gr]
completeNetwork::ggraphx = "At least one of the vertices `1` is a sink or source.";
completeNetworkStep[g_?GraphQ, list_] /; 
  And @@ (MemberQ[VertexList[g], #] & /@ list) := Module[{clist},
  (* connect the vertices*)
  clist = connect[g, list];
  (*remove sinks*)
  clist = FixedPoint[step[sinks][g, #] &, clist];
  (*remove sources*)
  clist = FixedPoint[step[sources][g, #] &, clist]]
completeNetwork[g_?GraphQ, list_] /; 
  And @@ (MemberQ[VertexList[g], #] & /@ list) := Module[{hgr},
  (* clean the network from sinks/sources*)
  hgr = healthyGraph[g];
  (* check if list of vertices is still part of the healthy graph*)
  If[
   And @@ (MemberQ[VertexList[hgr], #] & /@ list),
   FixedPoint[completeNetworkStep[hgr, #] &, list],
   Message[completeNetwork::ggraphx, list]; {}]
  ]
ShowCompleteSubgraph[g_?GraphQ, list_] := 
  HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, completeNetwork[g, list]]]
```

In many instances the algorithm works very good. Some problems remain though. Consider the following setup:

```
vertices = {30, 43, 57, 1, 75, 24, 74, 94, 62, 47, 51, 89, 95, 87, 5, 
 73, 80, 91, 3, 67, 4, 8, 93, 18, 85, 49, 39, 13, 45, 79, 96, 98, 
 81, 19, 21, 15, 10, 60, 77, 76};
edges = {85 -> 4, 94 -> 95, 45 -> 18, 75 -> 3, 80 -> 30, 15 -> 80, 
  51 -> 21, 15 -> 43, 13 -> 95, 75 -> 91, 4 -> 30, 95 -> 76, 
  94 -> 51, 95 -> 21, 30 -> 45, 81 -> 96, 39 -> 13, 89 -> 1, 76 -> 3,
  96 -> 47, 67 -> 77, 67 -> 10, 4 -> 24, 57 -> 89, 73 -> 95, 
  89 -> 51, 45 -> 80, 21 -> 8, 74 -> 73, 98 -> 96, 4 -> 76, 77 -> 79,
  43 -> 93, 15 -> 19, 3 -> 57, 76 -> 15, 94 -> 24, 45 -> 15, 
  75 -> 89, 73 -> 60, 3 -> 49, 98 -> 10, 1 -> 43, 10 -> 15, 49 -> 5, 
  8 -> 79, 51 -> 10, 60 -> 51, 3 -> 13, 60 -> 43, 96 -> 62, 57 -> 4, 
  45 -> 95, 67 -> 5, 1 -> 4, 98 -> 30, 39 -> 75, 39 -> 18, 89 -> 75, 
  89 -> 15, 43 -> 39, 60 -> 10, 91 -> 39, 85 -> 8, 47 -> 89, 
  57 -> 85, 76 -> 39, 98 -> 95, 51 -> 73, 76 -> 8, 30 -> 49, 
  87 -> 49, 77 -> 93, 80 -> 21, 96 -> 57, 39 -> 76, 39 -> 30, 
  62 -> 91, 94 -> 10, 96 -> 81, 95 -> 75, 62 -> 77, 3 -> 87, 
  43 -> 87, 49 -> 24, 21 -> 87, 94 -> 39, 94 -> 98, 87 -> 89, 
  5 -> 13, 21 -> 67, 47 -> 5, 62 -> 47, 39 -> 47, 91 -> 60, 96 -> 76,
  10 -> 79};
ini1 = {45, 4, 62, 15, 51};
exgr = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
{{sinks@#, sources@#} &@
  Subgraph[exgr, completeNetwork[exgr, ini1]], ini1, 
  completeNetwork[exgr, ini1]}
```

> {{{}, {96}}, {45, 4, 62, 15, 51}, {1, 4, 15, 21, 30, 43, 45, 47, 51, 
>        57, 62, 76, 87, 89, 96}}

You see that a source vertex (96) remains. The graph looks like

```
ShowCompleteSubgraph[exgr, completeNetwork[exgr, ini1]]
```

[image]

Apparently, vertex 62 from the initial list has only outgoing edges, except for 96->62. How can we modify the algorithm to open up routes along alternative edges?

Comment: **1.** In your example, it was not really necessary to select `7`, just selecting `9` would have been enough.  Is this correct?  **2.** Are you strict on condition 3, or an approximation will do?

Comment: @Szabolcs True. "7" was not neccessary. 2. No! I am not too strict on the minimization. I just want to prevent the solution to blow up.

Comment: This is unrelated, but I was wondering why the lines are thicker than the default in your figures.  Did you set a higher screen resolution?  If yes, which is the resolution option that will affect line widths too?  Another thing: if you convert the graph plots to graphics by prepending `Show` (e.g. `Show@Graph[...]`), then you won't need the `ImagePadding` workaround to avoid cutting off the vertex names.  (I'm still trying to come up with a solution to your question...)

Comment: @Szabolcs I wasn't aware that the lines are thicker, but I set the screen magnification to 150% at the bottom right of the window. Thanks for the tip with `Show@Graph`.

Comment: I changed the initial subset from {1,3} to {1,3,7} to make the solution somehwat more reasonable.

Comment: How about using `FindShortestPath` or related functions?  For question **1**, break the subgraph into components, then find a shortest path between two components (using an undirected version of `gr`).  Include the path in the subgraph.  Repeat until there's only one component in the subgraph.  For question **2**, find a sink/source, then find a shortest path (in the directed version of `gr`) to any other vertex of the subgraph.  Include the shortest path in the subgraph, then repeat until there are no sinks/sources.  It won't minimize the added nodes, but it should work ...

Comment: There's a mistake in `ex`: `"9" -> "1"` should be `"1" -> "9"` to match the graphics.  Also, `"6"` is a sink here.

Comment: Is it connected to electrical circuits problems?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov No, the background is to set up a closed chemical network from a large list chemical reactions, such that each included species has formation and destruction reactions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's denote the graph by `gr` and the initial subset of vertices by `v`.

#### Connecting the graph

First, we break the subgraph generated by `v` into connected components.  We select one vertex from the smallest connected component, and another one that is not in it.  We find the shortest path in the *undirected* `gr` that connects these two, and add all vertices from the shortest path to `v`.  Repeat until the subgraph becomes connected.

```
smallestComponent[g_Graph] := 
 With[{components = ConnectedComponents@UndirectedGraph[g]},
  Extract[components, Ordering[components, 1]]
 ]

connectStep[gr_, v_] :=
 Module[{sc, rest},
  sc = smallestComponent@Subgraph[gr, v];
  rest = Complement[v, sc];
  If[rest === {},
   v,
   Union[
    FindShortestPath[UndirectedGraph[gr], First[sc], First[rest]],
    v
    ]
   ]
  ]

connect[gr_, v_] := FixedPoint[connectStep[gr, #] &, v]
```

Usage:

```
connect[gr, {"1", "3", "7"}]

(* ==> {"1", "3", "7", "9"} *)
```

### Getting rid of sinks and sources

Let's assume that the subgraph is connected.

Take the subgraph, and select one sink from `v`.  Then select any other vertex and find the shortest path between these two in the *directed* `gr`, using the sink as starting point.  Add all vertices from the shortest path to `v`. Repeat until there are no sinks in the subgraph.

Sources can be removed in an analogous way, except they need to be end point of the path.

```
sinks[g_?GraphQ] := Pick[VertexList[g], VertexOutDegree[g], 0]
sources[g_?GraphQ] := Pick[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g], 0]

step[sinkOrSource_][gr_, v_] :=
 Module[{ss, s, t},
  ss = sinkOrSource[Subgraph[gr, v]];
  If[ss === {},
   v,

   s = First[ss];
   t = First@DeleteCases[v, s];
   If[sinkOrSource == source, {s,t} = {t,s}];
   Union[v, FindShortestPath[gr, s, t]]
   ]
  ]

FixedPoint[step[sink][gr, #]&, {"1", "3"}]

(* ==> {"1", "3", "9"} *)
```

Comment: neat! Give me some time to test it with different networks.

Comment: There are cases where the algorithm runs in circles. Consider: `FixedPoint[step[sources][gr, #] &, {"5", "3", "2"}]`. `"3"` is a source term, and remains so.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Sorry, my function is misleading because it seems that you can simply switch `sinks` to `sources`.  It is also necessary to exchange `s` and `t` in `FindShortestPath`.  I made a quick edit to fix it (a hack,r eally) but don't have time to test now...

Answer (score 4):

Most of the work can be done much simpler than Szabolcs' answer.

#### 1: Identify and get rid of sinks/sources and useless vertices in a single step

You can weed out all sinks/sources and vertices that will only lead to sinks/sources easily as follows:

```
{deadVtx, possibleVtx} = GatherBy[ConnectedComponents[gr], Length[#]==1 &];
```

You can see for yourself that any vertex in `deadVtx` will not lead you anywhere:
[image]

#### 2: Use `ConnectedGraphQ` to check for connectivity

Given an initial vertex list `initVtx`, you can:

1. use the above two vertex lists and `MemberQ` to check if the initial list contains any vertex from the `deadVtx` list and issue an error and stop if it does.
2. check if it is already connected with

   ```
   ConnectedGraphQ[Subgraph[gr, initVtx]]
   ```
3. add vertices only from the `possibleVtx` list if it is not already connected.

#### 3: Get components that are immediately connected using `VertexComponent`:

If it is not already connected, instead of adding an arbitrary, possibly distant vertex, you can pick one that is only 1 connection away from the existing vertices  with:

```
Complement[VertexComponent[sgr, initVtx, 1], initVtx]
```

---

I think the above can be worked into your vertex folding routine, and so I'm not doing that part.

Comment: `VertexComponent[gr, initVtx, 1]` will add *every* vertex that's distance one from *any* vertex in `initVtx`.  This might be a lot more than what's necessary to add to the set.

Comment: @Szabolcs No, I didn't suggest adding them all... I said _pick_ one from that smaller list. You still have to do a little search, but with a smaller set.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `` GraphComputation`SourceVertexList `` and `` GraphComputation`SinkVertexList `` to get the source and sink vertices and `VertexDelete` them using the function:

```
vdF = VertexDelete[#, Union[GraphComputation`SinkVertexList[#], 
     GraphComputation`SourceVertexList[#]]] &;
```

A `FixedPoint` of the function `vdF` will have no source or sink vertices.

Examples:

```
Row[{g1 = RandomGraph[{15, 20}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 300], 
  fp = FixedPoint[vdF, g1], HighlightGraph[g1, EdgeList[fp]]}]
```

[image]

```
ex = {"9" -> "7", "4" -> "6", "1" -> "9", "3" -> "5", "10" -> "8", 
 "5" -> "2", "2" -> "5", "9" -> "3", "3" -> "1", "7" -> "9", 
 "8" -> "6", "3" -> "10", "2" -> "1", "7" -> "4", "1" -> "4", 
 "2" -> "7", "5" -> "6", "7" -> "2"};

gr = Graph[ex, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{gr, fp = FixedPoint[vdF, gr], HighlightGraph[gr, EdgeList[fp]]}]
```

[image]

```
vertices = {30, 43, 57, 1, 75, 24, 74, 94, 62, 47, 51, 89, 95, 87, 5, 
   73, 80, 91, 3, 67, 4, 8, 93, 18, 85, 49, 39, 13, 45, 79, 96, 98, 
   81, 19, 21, 15, 10, 60, 77, 76};
edges = {85 -> 4, 94 -> 95, 45 -> 18, 75 -> 3, 80 -> 30, 15 -> 80, 
   51 -> 21, 15 -> 43, 13 -> 95, 75 -> 91, 4 -> 30, 95 -> 76, 
   94 -> 51, 95 -> 21, 30 -> 45, 81 -> 96, 39 -> 13, 89 -> 1, 76 -> 3,
    96 -> 47, 67 -> 77, 67 -> 10, 4 -> 24, 57 -> 89, 73 -> 95, 
   89 -> 51, 45 -> 80, 21 -> 8, 74 -> 73, 98 -> 96, 4 -> 76, 77 -> 79,
    43 -> 93, 15 -> 19, 3 -> 57, 76 -> 15, 94 -> 24, 45 -> 15, 
   75 -> 89, 73 -> 60, 3 -> 49, 98 -> 10, 1 -> 43, 10 -> 15, 49 -> 5, 
   8 -> 79, 51 -> 10, 60 -> 51, 3 -> 13, 60 -> 43, 96 -> 62, 57 -> 4, 
   45 -> 95, 67 -> 5, 1 -> 4, 98 -> 30, 39 -> 75, 39 -> 18, 89 -> 75, 
   89 -> 15, 43 -> 39, 60 -> 10, 91 -> 39, 85 -> 8, 47 -> 89, 
   57 -> 85, 76 -> 39, 98 -> 95, 51 -> 73, 76 -> 8, 30 -> 49, 
   87 -> 49, 77 -> 93, 80 -> 21, 96 -> 57, 39 -> 76, 39 -> 30, 
   62 -> 91, 94 -> 10, 96 -> 81, 95 -> 75, 62 -> 77, 3 -> 87, 
   43 -> 87, 49 -> 24, 21 -> 87, 94 -> 39, 94 -> 98, 87 -> 89, 
   5 -> 13, 21 -> 67, 47 -> 5, 62 -> 47, 39 -> 47, 91 -> 60, 96 -> 76,
    10 -> 79};

gr2 = Graph[vertices, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize->300];
Row[{gr2, fp = FixedPoint[vdF, gr2], HighlightGraph[gr2, EdgeList[fp]]}]
```

[image]